# Copy list of pointers no loops

Tags: c++, list, pointers, stdlist

i have a list with pointers to some Object.
i want to copy the list but with new pointers.

i mean every element in list , to do new to object and insert the new adress in new list.

i try to use with:

```
 std::list<Course*> tmp;

 tmp = courses; // courses is list<Course*>.

 std::for_each(tmp.begin(), tmp.end(), ReplaceAllCells());



class ReplaceAllCells {
public:
    ReplaceAllCells(){}
     void operator( )( Course* course) {
         course = new Course(*course);
    }
};
```

after the call to function i get new list with same pointers... the value of tmp no changed..
How can i fix that without use any loops? 
thanks.

Comment: Is your `Shift` key broken?

Comment: I kinda like Froot Loops.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Function arguments are passed by value in C, if you don't use a reference type. When you have:

```
void f(T t)
{
     t = something.....
}
```

this only affects the local copy `t`, not the variable that was given as argument to this function call. Whether or not `T` is a pointer type makes no difference

You need to accept the argument by reference if you want to modify it, `T &t` here, or in your case `Course * &course`.